# resetting column values after time

Tags: mysql, timer, mysql-event

I am fairly new to phpmyadmin and SQL Databases.

I would like to know how I can add a "script" that resets a value in all columns of a table after a certain time period -> I want the column to set the int value to 0 every 72hours for every row.
Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is called an "event".  Here's a potential definition; your needs may vary.

```
CREATE EVENT `zero_my_column`
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 72 HOUR STARTS '2015-07-13 00:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
    ENABLE
DO BEGIN
         UPDATE mytable SET counter = 0 WHERE counter <> 0;
END
```

There's some [configuration work to do](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html) to ensure your MySQL server will run this event correctly.

This is the actual update query.

```
UPDATE mytable SET counter = 0 WHERE counter <> 0;
```

Notice the `WHERE` clause. That prevents redundant updating of rows that already have a zero column value for `counter.`

Comment: On StackOverflow, it's best to mark an answer Accepted (click the green check) if it helped. That way, others with similar questions can find your question and the answer.

Comment: Since you mention using phpMyAdmin, you may be interested in the "Events" tab which you can see from any database page.